# ¿Cómo pasar archivos wav a mp3 con Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Estoy intentando convertir un archivo .wav a mp3 con python, probé instalar pymedia pero no me lo permitió ya que utilizó python 3.7 y probé con el código de pydub que encontré pero no me funciona, me dice que no encuentra el archivo. Estos son los códigos que probé:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', './prueba.wav',
                   './cambiado.mp3'])
```

El siguiente es con pydub:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

AudioSegment.from_wav("./prueba.wav").export("./cambiado.mp3", format="mp3")
```

La cosa es que ambos me dan el mismo error:

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
> ```

Y el segundo aunque me logro generar un archivo, windows no me deja abrirlo por el formato, dice que no es correcto o que quizás es corrupto.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar [Lame un conocido codificador y decodificador de MP3](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAME_(codificador)).
Puedes descargar la versión 32 o 64 bits desde [aqui](https://rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php).

Simplemente descárgalo y descomprímelo en algún directorio visible. Luego, debes configurar la variable de entorno `PATH` para apuntar a los binarios de Lame. Es decir, agregas el directorio donde esta `lame.exe` a `PATH`.

```
import subprocess
def wav_to_mp3(source_path, out_path):
  cmd = 'lame --preset insane \"{}\" \"{}\"'.format(source_path, out_path)
  exitcode = subprocess.call(cmd)
  returne exitcode
```

Con el `preset insane` logras obtener la mejor calidad de compresión (`320 kpbs`) sin sacrificar tanto espacio, aunque se puede regular (consulta `--help`).